# Move an 8 bit register to a 16 bit memory location, how?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, 8-bit

I have problem moving 8 bit register to a 16 bit register.

What i'm trying to do is to divide a number repeatedly by 10 til it gets lower than 10, and, within each division time, i try to move out the remained part of the division out from AH register, add 48 to it, then i could have its Ascii code , then i try to show the digit i got , on screen.

```
 Num1 DW 255
 DIVISION :
        CMP NUM1,10
            Jl DIVEND
            
        MOV AX,10
        DIV NUM1
        MOV NUM1,AL    ;*  Operand types do not match
    
        
        ADD AH,48
        MOV DL,AH; 
        MOV AH,02H
        INT 21H
        
    JMP DIVISION
```

but , when im trying to assemble it , it says , `Operand types do not match` on the line indicated by *.

im using turbo assembler V4.1 ...

Comment: Can't remember much from Turbo Assembler, but did you try `MOV BYTE NUM1,AL`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing MOV NUM1,AL is moving the contents of AL into NUM1? this can't happen can it?

Comment: @PreetSangha Right, I missed that entirely just looking at the syntax :)

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: look , all im trying to do , is to print the reversed form of a number , and , no it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Joachim , you mean MOV BYTE PTR NUM1,AL ? no it didnt work .

Comment: You're dividing 10 by 255. I ASSume you want to divide 255 by 10.

Comment: `Num1` isn't a register, it's static storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean that?

```
mov bx, Offset Num1 
mov [bx], al
```

The error you get is because you declare a word but adress it as a byte. If you did Num1 db it also works.

Tested with TASM 4.1

Comment: It's not necessary to put the address in a register (to hide it from the assembler's build-time size checking).  You can just override the size with `mov byte ptr [Num1], al` to tell the assembler you really mean it.  Of course for a simple case like this, usually you don't want to store only part of the storage you declared.  So using `db` would be the better approach.

Comment: So basically this current answer silences the error, but doesn't fix the possible problem, which is dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

As for the more general question in the title: you use `movzx` (move zero extend) for unsigned values and `movsx` (move sign extend) for signed values.

Comment: I changed the question title to reflect the code; the title was incorrect and didn't match the accepted answer.  But yes, for a word <- byte load, or actual reg, reg copy, yes `movzx` or `movsx` are good.  (For a store, you can extend into a wider register and store that.)